# Should I use Roboto font for All widgets in all places?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-fonts

I am applying Roboto fonts for my first Android application. I am wondering that should I apply Roboto font for All widgets in All Places to make font consistent in whole application OR I should apply the font for some widgets in some places that I need to?

Note that my application need to support any language text display (entered by end-users).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-roboto-noto): "To support all languages worldwide, Google recommends using Roboto for languages that use the Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic scripts and Noto for all other languages."

Comment: Thank you! Do you think I can use Noto font for all languages?

Comment: Based on my investigation, using Noto for all languages does appear to work better than trying to switch between Roboto and Noto (especially on older Android versions), but it does come at a cost... the Noto zip file that contains all fonts is currently ~380MB.  If you need to redistribute all of these your APK is likely to become much larger.